# How to determine the foliation of an involutive distribution?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, foliations

The question is as follows:

Consider the distribution $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by the vector fields:

$$ X_1 =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos x \cos y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}, ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ 
 X_2 =  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \sin x \sin y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
Check that $D$ is involutive and determine the foliation $F$ that integrates it.

$\textbf{Some attempt:}$

We have 
\begin{align}[X_1 , X_2] &= [\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos x \cos y \frac{\partial}{\partial z} , \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \sin x \sin y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}] \\&= - \cos x \sin y \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \sin y \cos x \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\&= 0 \end{align}
So it is involutive.

And we know that since $D$ is  involutive, therefore, is integrable. And we know that the integral manifolds of an integrable distribution define a foliation of our manifold.

So how can we find the foliation in our example parcticaly?

Can someone help me to understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differential forms win again. Note that $D$ is given by $\omega = 0$, where 
$$\omega = dz-\cos x\cos y\,dx + \sin x\sin y\,dy.$$
As it happens, $d\omega = 0$ [in general, integrability will be couched in the statement that $d\omega \wedge\omega = 0$], so $\omega$ is exact. Indeed, $\omega = df$, where $f(x,y,z)= z - \sin x\cos y$. Thus the foliation is given by the level sets $f(x,y,z) = z-\sin x\cos y = c$ as $c$ varies over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Many thanks! But can you please let me know that how did you find $\omega = dz-\cos x\cos y\,dx + \sin x\sin y\,dy?$ I know that $D = \left< X_1, X_2 \right >$, but I cannot see why the sign of $\cos x \cos y$ has changed to minus and the sign of $\sin x \sin y$ has changed to plus and also I think there should be two $dz$? Can you please explain more? Thanks!

Comment: Try checking $\omega(X_1)$ and $\omega(X_2)$.

Comment: Thanks! I think you mean we have to get zero for each of them. But I am not getting zero! Can you please do one of them for me to see how it's done?

Comment: You need to learn some basics before worrying about involutivity of distributions! Just apply linearity and $dx(\partial/\partial x) = 1$, $dx(\partial/\partial y) = dx(\partial/\partial z) = 0$, etc.

Comment: Many thanks! I understood! I was doing it wrong!

Comment: Hi, just confused. Is it generally true that the differential forms defining the involutive distribution exact? Though I think I kind of saw they are closed from Morita...

Comment: @chikurin  In general, not even closed. Read my answer carefully. But on $\Bbb R^3$ every closed form is exact.

Comment: Thanks!! Don't they generate the differential ideal? Or is it actually another thing?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Do you know a good reference of foliations that uses differential forms?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $[X_1,X_2]=0$, the foliation is defined by $\phi_\circ\psi_t{t'}(u)$ where $\phi_t$ is the flow of $X_1$ and $\psi_t$ the flow of $X_2$, $u(x,y,z)$ and $t,t'\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Many thanks! Can you also please explain that how can we find it in general. For example, how can we find a foliation that integrates a 1 dimensional distribution $X = A \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + B \frac{\partial}{\partial y } + C \frac{\partial}{\partial z } + D \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega }$, for $A, B, C$ and $D$ functions of $x, y, z$ and $\omega$. Or for instance let $A= -y, B = x, C = - \omega$ and $D = z$. Thanks!